# KiCad submodule with terminal

Tags: kicad

Is it possible to create multiple submodules (hierarchical sheets) that represent separate pcbs and are connected by terminals/wires in the master scheme?
If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  I tried to do this and asked questions on other forums on how to do this.

You need a  new project for each sub-board.  Maybe in the future though, after the volunteers get to it.